# How to run application automatically using scanner "honeywell"

Tags: barcode-scanner, honeywell

This is my code that I use. Please correct me if I'm wrong. I just really want to learn as freshman student

My project is using barcode I need to use scanner to read the code at the same time  automatically open the application set on that code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As keyPressEventArgs) 
   Handle textbox1.keypress
   If e.keypress=ChrW(15)Then
      Textbox1.text=""
   end if
End sub
```

Also I use

```
Process.Start("d:\windows\notepad.exe")
```

It works, but my target is automatically open without clicking any button

I'm still searching for next code. Any idea is very much appreciated

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Documentation: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/685e9790-2f16-4141-9c01-9d8030035414/using-vbnet-to-run-external-applications?forum=vbgeneral

But generally it's the following command

```
proc = Process.Start("d:\windows\notepad.exe", "")
```